# How to share internet from PC over Zyxel NWA 1100-n on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, windows-xp, router

I have my old PC computer with Windows XP sp3. On this computer I get internet from network card Airlive WT-2000PCI which is upgraded in. I have Zyxel NWA1100-N and one ethernet cable. I would like my other devices (mobile phone,laptop) connect via wireless. Is it possible to share my PC's internet just by connecting my PC and Zyxel with ethernet cable? Do I need something else?

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you are asking.  The Zyxel device is a router correct?  Can't you just have your mobile phone and laptop connect to the wireless network?

Comment: Yes. Zyxel is router. I cannot connect from my mobile phone or laptop, because I get internet from my old PC. So I would like to do it via router if it is possible.

Comment: _I get internet from my old PC_, your old PC provides you internet?  I don't think that's possible.  Usually, you have a modem (that provides an internet connection) which plugs into a router (the Zyxel device).  The router creates a wireless signal that your Network Card in your PC picks up and uses to connect to the internet.  The router should be broadcasting a signal that your phone and laptop can detect.  It should be named something similar to your router brand name (SSID).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly: you're getting your Internet from a wireless adapter and want to share that connection with other devices that aren't able to connect to that same wireless network directly.

It should be possible to plug your Zyxel into your PC and use the PC as a gateway for the wireless network the Zyxel provides.

You'll need to:

- Setup Internet Connection Sharing on your PC. It should ask which
  connection you want to share and where to share it, (your Ethernet
  port.) See this page for more information: http://www.practicallynetworked.com/sharing/xp_ics/
- Manually assign the Ethernet adapter a static IP address and subnet mask. E.g.: 10.0.0.1 & 255.255.255.0
- Manually assign the Zyxel an address in the same subnet as your
  Ethernet adapter. (10.0.0.2 & 255.255.255.0). Set the gateway to your PC's address, (10.0.0.1).
- Configure the Zyxel's wireless settings, SID, password, etc.
- Configure the Zyxel's networking settings to provide clients connecting to the wifi: DHCP, DNS, subnet mask,  Here you'll probably want to use another subnet: 192.168.1.1 & 255.255.255.0.

This essentially creates a double NAT setup for you, (only important to know if you want to have a server running off another device and need inbound traffic to be able to reach it.)